# Yoast SEO canonical URL gets pointed to the homepage

Tags: permalinks, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, rel-canonical

I noticed in Google Search Console that pages are increasingly getting removed from the index due to their canonical. For some reason — it points to the home page for some articles.

After some digging, I found out that the canonical is essentially derived from the `permalink` stored in the `wp_yoast_indexable` table. It's [this line from the plugin's source](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/a0c60a0211bcebfeaf102d781754df0cb8a7b379/src/repositories/indexable-repository.php#L332):

```php
    public function find_by_id_and_type( $object_id, $object_type, $auto_create = true ) {
        $indexable = $this->query()
            ->where( 'object_id', $object_id )
            ->where( 'object_type', $object_type )
            ->find_one();
        // ...
```

It pulls out the object from the database and if I run execute `$indexable->permalink`, I get `"/"`.

I opened the table in phpMyAdmin and the record indeed had `permalink` set to `/` there. Other posts had normal permalinks. So it seems that the database was messed up by something.

The actual WordPress post does not have a custom permalink. However, if I set one and remove it — the record in the database is refreshed, the `permalink` in `wp_yoast_indexable` is no longer `/`, and the canonical is as expected.

Do you have an idea what could have possibly set the permalinks to `/`?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that all problematic posts had their `wp_yoast_indexable` row updated a few months ago which exactly matched with when I ran a script to update all existing posts. It was something like this:

```php
$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($posts as $i => $post) {
    $post_data = array(
        'ID' => $post->ID,
        // other stuff
    );

    wp_update_post($post_data);
}
```

The problem was that I ran the script from the CLI, where `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is not set.

Apparently, when you run `wp_update_post()`, Yoast SEO runs and updates its own tables. If `HTTP_HOST` is missing, the updated permalink turns to something like `http:///the-post-slug/`. That's what I saw in the debugger. My guess is that it gets sanitized at some point and finally turns to `/`.

To fix this, all I had to do was to run an empty `wp_update_post()` on all problematic posts while `HTTP_HOST` is set:

```php
<?php

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'example.com';

require '/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-load.php';

global $wpdb;

$query = <<<SQL
SELECT object_id
FROM wp_yoast_indexable
WHERE permalink='/';
SQL;

$result = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
$ids = array_column($result, 'object_id');

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    wp_update_post(['ID' => $id]);
}
```